# Replicating data from SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: oracle10g

I have a view which pulls data from SQL server through database link.

something like select * from codelkp@sql_link;

As this table is very frequently used (selected) in my database code, to eliminate the network turn-around time, I am planning to dump all the data from the table codelkp(this is SQL server table accessed through dblink) into my oracle table lets say codelkp_orcl and use that. How can I replicate any data change in codelkp table to codelkp_orcl? I can write a procedure to delete codelkp_orcl and reload from codelkp but meanwhile if my application doesn't find data in codelkp_orcl table then it will causes functional issues. Please suggest a fix.